# Selenium ghost running tests again after all are done?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I have multiple test for clicking through my .net web app with selenium and chromedriver.
If I run all my tests everything works fine, but after all are done and the test window in VS shows that it is done, they start again (I see the tests in the browser being clicked), but the background doesn't show any tests running.

I tried using debug to see if there is some kind of repetetition, but the tests are officially done and closed before the ghost run.
Has anyone seen this before? Is this because of chromedriver, selenium, VS?

Comment: Are you using **Selenium Grid**? If you are using a Selenium Grid for parallel test execution, it is possible that the tests are being executed again on a different node.

Comment: Please share the driver creation code, sounds like you have a problem of multiple driver creations for each test. also you should check with a single test before executing them all